# Laravel cache routes in browser

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-blade

I have simple laravel application and I use simple blade template.
I have navigtion, imageine two routes: `main` and `contact`. when I enter website, main html file loads, it takes about 2 seconds. then I go to contact page, it loads in 2 seconds too. when I navigate to main page, it loads this page from zero, and it takes still 2 seconds.
So is there any possible workaround to cache this already visited routes? so when I navigate back to main page, it won't be necessary to wait this 2 seconds again?

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the routes with `php artisan route:cache`, and cache the views with `php artisan view:cache`

Comment: that doesn't make any performance improvement. it should be cached inside browser

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is to store the Site in a cache that deploys it back to the user on no time, check out PHP Varnish then.

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/varnish-cache/